# use Turtlebot's sensors for obstacle avoidance

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, what is used of the cliff sensors on turtlebot? Could i employ this four sensors to use them in a algorithm of obstacle avoidance?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44103/use-turtlebot%27s-sensors-for-obstacle-avoidance/) by [Yuri](https://answers.ros.org/users/2892/yuri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Cliff/Wheel-Drop sensors in TurtleBot are used to prevent it from falling off the stairs or ledges. It sends a (0,0) velocity when it senses a wheel drop. You can't use Cliff Sensors alone for Obstacle Avoidance.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2012-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4